# Use same Cognito UserPool with Lamda Function and Resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I'm using the serverless framework and I need to override some default values for the UserPool created by the Lambda function. What's the correct way to do it?
My `serverless.yml` is creating two `user-pool` (same name), one for the lambda function and another for the `UserPool` resource:

```
service: userpool

custom:
  stage: dev
  poolName: user-pool

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:custom.stage}

functions:
  preSignUp:
    handler: handler.preSignUp
    events:
      - cognitoUserPool:
          pool: ${self:custom.poolName}
          trigger: PreSignUp

resources:
  Resources:
    UserPool:
      Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
      Properties:
        UserPoolName: ${self:custom.poolName}
        AliasAttributes:
          - email
        AutoVerifiedAttributes:
          - email
        Schema:
          - Name: name
            AttributeDataType: String
            Mutable: true
            Required: true
          - Name: email
            AttributeDataType: String
            Mutable: false
            Required: true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the Serverless documentation in https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources/#aws---resources

If you have created a Cognito User Pool resource which follows this format **CognitoUserPool{normalizedPoolId}**, you can give the **normalizedPoolId** for each of your lambda functions.

In your case you have defined the Cognito User Pool as "*CognitoUserPool**TestPool***" which allows you to use TestPool in your lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

It works now, but can someone explain to me how? How the code below knows that the Cognito resource and the pool created by the event are the same?

```
service: userpool

custom:
  stage: dev

environment:
  USER_POOL: userPool

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:custom.stage}

functions:
  preSignUp:
    handler: handler.preSignUp
    events:
      - cognitoUserPool:
          pool: TestPool
          trigger: PreSignUp

resources:
  Resources:
    CognitoUserPoolTestPool:
      Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
      Properties:
        AliasAttributes:
          - email
        AutoVerifiedAttributes:
          - email
        Schema:
          - Name: name
            AttributeDataType: String
            Mutable: true
            Required: true
          - Name: email
            AttributeDataType: String
            Mutable: false
            Required: true
```

Comment: Try removing the entire stack and all the user pools (I don't think CF deletes them automatically) and redeploying, just to ensure it works.

Answer (score 0):

This problem solved in a better way in new release:

[Add support for existing Cognito User Pools](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/6362)

Your function event should look like this:

```
functions:
  preSignUp:
    handler: handler.preSignUp
    events:
      - cognitoUserPool:
          pool: ${self:custom.poolName}
          trigger: PreSignUp
          existing: true
```

No need to add additional "CognitoUserPool" in front of the resource definition.